# Smartsheet-api and Python SDK certificate verify failed

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am having a basic problem with the SmartSheet Python SDK.
I am using Python 3.4

Using the following sample code from the SmartSheet docs:

```
import smartsheet

smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet(MY_TOKEN_HERE)

me = smartsheet.Users.get_current_user()

print(me)
```

the line `me = smartsheet.Users.get_current_user()`

will cause multiple errors of this type

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

My token works with both REST API via POSTMAN and simply using Python/Requests functionality

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please use markup language to format the code properly (4 spaces before code lines, or use the icon in the toolbar above the text edit box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you try using version 2015.04.28 of certifi:

```
pip uninstall certifi
pip install certifi==2015.04.28
```

Comment: That did it  !! Works perfect now !

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Can you please mark this as an accepted answer (so that others may benefit from this info in the future)?  Thank you!